# Why does pytesseract configuration using PSM 12 detect text but not PSM 6 with this image?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to understand why one PSM mode works better for this image.

[image]

Setup:
Python 3.7.9
Pytesseract 0.3.9
Tesseract 5.1

Snippet of code:

```
custom_config_psm12 = r'--oem 3 --psm 12 -c page_separator='''
custom_config_psm6 = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 -c page_separator='''

image_data_table = pytesseract.image_to_data(im,config=custom_config_psm6)  # Doesn't detect anything
image_data_table = pytesseract.image_to_data(im,config=custom_config_psm12) # detects and recognizes text perfectly
```

Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A block represents a paragraph. Your image is a line of text, so it would have better results with a line-oriented PSM, such as 7 or 12.

```
Page segmentation modes:
  0    Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
  1    Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
  2    Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR. (not implemented)
  3    Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
  4    Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
  5    Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
  6    Assume a single uniform block of text.
  7    Treat the image as a single text line.
  8    Treat the image as a single word.
  9    Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
 10    Treat the image as a single character.
 11    Sparse text. Find as much text as possible in no particular order.
 12    Sparse text with OSD.
 13    Raw line. Treat the image as a single text line,
       bypassing hacks that are Tesseract-specific.
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  What about PSM 11?